# How do I change the background image on the push of a button between 100 different images? HTML/CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the background image of my div "title" on the push of a button and also have that image stay as the background until the button is pressed again using cookies. I have 100 images labeled IMG_1.jpg - IMG_100.jpg.

I tried to change the background to just one image first but this didn't work.

```js
function changeBackground() {
  document.title.style.background = 'url(../img/bc/IMG_10.jpg) no-repeat';
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav__list">
    <li class="nav__list-item">
      <a onclick="changeBackground()" class="nav__link nav__link--btn">
        Change Theme
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="title">
</div>
```

Comment: Please show a more complete snippet that we can run. How have you defined title for example?

Comment: Hello Begonio, I see you are just starting out. Make sure to check out a tutorial about web-development like this one https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp . While Stack Overflow does help if you have questions, most of the common ones are already answered and you will find them if you search using the right keywords. In your case search for how to select a dom element and how to concat strings to build your background style string.

Comment: `document.title` does not refer to a div with class=title.  Try `document.querySelector(".title")`

Comment: A very useful way of helping to debug a bit of JS is to use your browser's dev tools inspect facility and look at the console. This will show you in this case that where you are trying to change the style the element is undefined, that is because document.title is meaningless (will be null). Learn about querySelector and similar methods by searching, MDN is a reliable source.

Answer (score 0):

try that

```js
let count = 1;
document.querySelector('#change-image').addEventListener('click', evt => {
  count += 1;
  let url = 'url("https://picsum.photos/id/' + count + '/300/200")';
  document.querySelector('.title').style.backgroundImage = url;
})
```

```css
.title {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/1/300/200");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<button id="change-image">Change Image</button>

<div class="title">
</div>
```

CSS and HTML, just for the example.

The important for you is the way the background image is changed and the format of the url to change.

To change it's:

```js
element.style.backgroundImage = ???
```

Format for the url is:

url("myBkgImage")

so to put in the previous style:

```js
element.style.backgroundImage = 'url("+ myVariabeImage +");
```

you can also notation ${myvar}